# How to calculate the swap (rollover) in mt5 in term of account currency

Tags: metatrader4, mql4, metatrader5, mql5

Backgound:

- using mt5
- "swap" (rollover) price is defined in points (0.00001/0.001) - 5-digit broker
- account currency: USD

The question is: how to calculate the "swap value" in terms of acc. currency in mt5. With other words, how many cents i will paid for one day rollover?

Currently have this "mql5" script:

```
#include <Trade\SymbolInfo.mqh>

void OnStart() {

   CSymbolInfo sym;  // symbol informations object
   sym.Name( ChartSymbol() ); // get the object for the current chart symbol

   if( sym.SwapMode() == SYMBOL_SWAP_MODE_POINTS) {

      double lot = 0.1;

      double swapUSD_long = sym.SwapLong() * 0;   // need help here
      double swapUSD_short = sym.SwapShort() * 0; // need help here

      PrintFormat(
         "symbol: %s swap_long: %.2f swap_short: %.2f swapUSD_long: %.2f swapUSD_short: %.2f",
         sym.Name(),
         sym.SwapLong(),
         sym.SwapShort(),
         swapUSD_long,
         swapUSD_short
      );
   }
}
```

When attaching the script to EURAUD, it prints to terminal:

> symbol: EURAUD swap_long: -10.80 swap_short: 6.80 swapUSD_long: 0.00
>   swapUSD_short: 0.00

so: the rollover price is 6.8 points for the short position. How to convert it to USD with current rate? For this need:

- find the pair with the acc currency (in this case need find AUDUSD)
- get the rate of AUDUSD sym.Bid() or sym.Ask()
- and ...

simply need some help ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right your question, you can use the `TickValueProfit` and `TickValueLoss`. If the swap to some direction is negative (you will pay) use the TickvalueLoss and when positive use TickValueProfit.

You can make a function for this like the next:

```
double swap_value_currency(double value_point, double tickprofit, double tickloss)
   {
      if( value_point == 0.0 ) { return(0.0); }
      if( value_point < 0.0 ) {
         return( val * tickloss );
      }
      return( value_point * tickprofit);
   }
```

The `swap_value_currency` returns the swap value depending on winning or losing for one standard lot.

so your fragment of code can be:

```
if( sym.SwapMode() == SYMBOL_SWAP_MODE_POINTS)
   {
      double swval_long = swap_value_currency(sym.SwapLong(),   sym.TickValueProfit(), sym.TickValueLoss());
      double swval_short= swap_vallue_currency(sym.SwapShort(), sym.TickValueProfit(), sym.TickValueLoss() );
   }
```

and because this is for one standard lot, you need multiply it with your lot size...